# React Typescript hooks and props

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-hooks, react-props, react-typescript

This is my first project using Typescript and also React Native. I just create a simple logic on App.tsx then, I tried to split it with a component. But, when I pass the props from the Modal component I get an error ts(2322). I know the code needs to be improve as it is my first time using Typescript. I do not know if someone could help me guiding me about it.
Below is the original App.tsx I did:

```
import { Button, FlatList, Modal, StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, View } from 'react-native';

import React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';

export interface AppProps {
  id: string | number;
  item: string;
  name: string;
  placeholder: string;
  value: string
}
 
const App: React.FC<AppProps> = () => {
  const [textInput, setTextInput] = useState<string>('');
  const [itemList, setItemList] = useState<any[]>([]);

  const [itemSelected, setItemSelected] = useState<any>({});
  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const handlerConfirmDelete = () => {
    setItemList(itemList.filter(item => item.id !== itemSelected.id));
    setItemSelected({});
    setModalVisible(false);
  }

  const handlerModalOpen = (id: string) => {
    setItemSelected(itemList.find(item => item.id === id));
    setModalVisible(true);
  }

  const onHandlerChangeText = (textValue: string) => setTextInput(textValue);
  const handleAddPress = () => {
    setItemList([
      ...itemList,
      {
        id: Math.random().toString(),
        value: textInput,
      },
    ]);
  }
  return (
    <>
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.firstInputs}>        
        <TextInput placeholder='Item de Lista'
        onChangeText={onHandlerChangeText}
        value={textInput} />
        <Button title='Add' onPress={handleAddPress} />
      </View>
      <View>
        <FlatList
        data={itemList}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        renderItem={(data) => (
          <View>          
            <Text>{data.item.value}</Text>  
            <Button title='X' onPress={() => handlerModalOpen(data.item.id)} />        
          </View>
        )}      
        />
      </View>   
    </View>
    <Modal animationType='slide' visible={modalVisible}>
      <View>
        <Text>Borrar</Text>
      </View>
      <View>
        <Text>seguro q borramos?</Text>
      </View>
      <View>
        <Text>{itemSelected.value}</Text>
      </View>
      <View>
        <Button onPress={handlerConfirmDelete} title='Confirm' />
      </View>
    </Modal>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is the new App.tsx and the Modal.tsx:
App.tsx

```
import { Button, FlatList, Modal, StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, View } from 'react-native';

import ModalComponent from './components/Modal';
import React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';

export interface AppProps {
  id: string | number;
  item: string;
  name: string;
  placeholder: string;
  value: string
}
 
const App: React.FC<AppProps> = () => {
  const [textInput, setTextInput] = useState<string>('');
  const [itemList, setItemList] = useState<any[]>([]);

  const [itemSelected, setItemSelected] = useState<any>({});
  const [modalVisible, setModalVisible] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const handlerConfirmDelete = () => {
    setItemList(itemList.filter(item => item.id !== itemSelected.id));
    setItemSelected({});
    setModalVisible(false);
  }

  const handlerModalOpen = (id: string) => {
    setItemSelected(itemList.find(item => item.id === id));
    setModalVisible(true);
  }

  const onHandlerChangeText = (textValue: string) => setTextInput(textValue);
  const handleAddPress = () => {
    setItemList([
      ...itemList,
      {
        id: Math.random().toString(),
        value: textInput,
      },
    ]);
  }
  return (
    <>
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.firstInputs}>        
        <TextInput placeholder='Item de Lista'
        onChangeText={onHandlerChangeText}
        value={textInput} />
        <Button title='Add' onPress={handleAddPress} />
      </View>
      <View>
        <FlatList
        data={itemList}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        renderItem={(data) => (
          <View>          
            <Text>{data.item.value}</Text>  
            <Button title='X' onPress={() => handlerModalOpen(data.item.id)} />        
          </View>
        )}      
        />
      </View>   
    </View>
    <ModalComponent modalVisible={modalVisible} itemSelected={itemSelected} handlerConfirmDelete={handlerConfirmDelete} />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Modal.tsx

```
import { Button, Modal, StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";

import { AppProps } from "../../App";

export interface ModalComponentProps {
    props: AppProps
    
}
 
const ModalComponent: React.FC<ModalComponentProps> = (props: any) => {
    
    const {modalVisible, itemSelected, handlerConfirmDelete} = props;
    return (
        <>
            <Modal animationType='slide' visible={modalVisible}>
                <View style={styles.modalContainer}>           
                    <View style={[styles.modalContent, styles.shadow]}>
                        <Text style={styles.modalMessage}>Seguro deseas borrar?</Text>
                        <Text style={styles.modalTitle}>{itemSelected.value}</Text>                    
                        <View>
                            <Button onPress={handlerConfirmDelete} title='Confirm' />
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </Modal>
        </>
    );
}
export default ModalComponent;
```

I haven't put the styles yet as I want first to make it work correctly. Thanks in advance.

This is the error:
Type '{ modalVisible: boolean; itemSelected: any; handlerConfirmDelete: () => void; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ModalComponentProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
Property 'modalVisible' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ModalComponentProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'.

Comment: What is the error? What are you trying to do, and what exactly is not working?

Comment: Hi @windowsill the error is this 
Type '{ modalVisible: boolean; itemSelected: any; handlerConfirmDelete: () => void; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ModalComponentProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
  Property 'modalVisible' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & ModalComponentProps & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
I am trying to pass the props of Modal.tsx to the App.tsx
I have those errors from Typescript that it makes the app not working

Comment: Please add the error in the question 

Comment: I jus added it to the question @SamridhTuladhar

Comment: Got it, you've written the wrong interface for `ModalComponent`, i'll just write out the correct interface in the answer 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some basics here:

1. If you use `React.FC<DataType>`, the `DataType` is automatically applied to the `props` of the component, but you have done `props:any` in `ModalComponent`, this would have bypassed the compile issue, but it would break things later on. So, change `props:any` to just `props`.

Tip: Just hover over `props` in VSCode, it's intellisense will show you it's datatype

2. You are using `AppProps` in `App.tsx` as `React.FC<AppProps>`, if you change it to `const App: React.FC<AppProps> = (props) => {...}`, and hover over `props` again, you can see the intellisense doing it's magic, but since it's not used anywhere in the code, you can remove it.

Now on to the core problem, if you hover over `props` you can see what it contains, it will only contain `props: AppProps` which isn't used anywhere in your code.

Instead change it to :

```
interface ModalComponentProps {
   modalVisible: boolean
   itemSelected: any // you have set any in App.tsx
   handlerConfirmDelete: () => void
    
}
```

and it should work. I still think you will have issue with `styles` as I don't know where it is imported from.

I would recommend to use `object` instead of `any`, or a custom interface over `object`. `any` will make things easy for now and bite you later.

Comment: Thanks for your help Samridh! There are style components on each .tsx I just didn't add them to the question.

Comment: Cool, you're welcome! Unwanted tip: If typescript gives you problem during compilations.... that's what it was designed to do  It's supposed to catch these issues before it reaches production, so try to avoid `any` as much as you can. There are other datatypes like `object`, `unknown`, `never` etc, that you should explore 